# How to fix breakpoint expressions in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

With VS2012 you could use some collection methods in breakpoint expressions such as this:

```
test.Contains("3")
```

However, with 2017 this throws the following error:

> The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. The condition was
>   'test.Contains("3")'. The error returned was 'error CS1061: 'string[]'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and no accessible
>   extension method 'Contains' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)'. Click OK to stop at this breakpoint.

Has this just something to do with my VS2017 instance or did they break something in 2017? Does anyone know how to resolve it. Breakpoint expressions were great in 2012 but they're pretty much useless in 2017.

Comment: Your error involves `string[]` rather than `string`. Are you sure that `test` is not inadvertently an array rather than a string?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in my Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version `15.9.5`. My conditional breakpoint `test.Contains("foo")` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `test` to be of type `List<string>` or `string[]` (just as the error message suggests)?

*If you meant to use [System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains), just fix the type of `test`.*

---

*If you want `test` to be of type `string[]`, read to end.*

The error you are receiving is the same Compiler Error you would get if you would write the Conditional Expression from the Breakpoint in code:

```cs
using System;

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] test = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

        test.Contains("3"); //Compiler Error
    }
}
```

`string[]` does not contain a definition for `Contains` accepting a first argument of type `string`.

In order to access the extension method [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) in the Namespace `System.Linq`, you need to bring it into scope with this `using` directive in code:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

Additionally, you need to use any type or method from that namespace in code, in order for the breakpoint condition to work as expected.

Alternatively, you may call the method directly:

```cs
System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(test, "3")
```

However, you still need to add the corresponding `using` directive and actually use any type or method from that namespace in code.

Comment: Hi, yeah this was because the variable was of type List<string>, not string[], however I'm sure this used to just work in older versions - not confirmed it yet though.